# Hadoop Map Output Type For Performance

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a bunch of fields to be written out by the Mapper around 10 fields.
Which way would be faster 
1. write out the fields as  the following

```
    tradeDate.readFields(in);
    marketMakerId.readFields(in);
    eventTime.readFields(in);
    bidPrice.readFields(in);
    .........................
```

or 2. convert them to a single Text field (tradeDate,marketId,evenTime,bidPrice....) and construct back the object on the Reducer.

Which way could give a better performance out of these?

Answer (score 1):

As usual, benchmarks could help. You can use [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks) to check hypothesis.

But in general, binary formats faster, when text<->binary conversions involved.
Consequently, I think, binary read/writeFields will work faster.